# Activation Email/Link Not Working

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, email, activation

I'm trying to send an activation email and have the user activate their account by clicking on the link provided. I have been tweaking it based on open source code I've been looking at online, however it has recently stopped sending the email without giving any errors. Here is the sign up form with the send email function:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls


Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim boolCar As Object

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    If txtEmailAddress.Text.Trim.EndsWith("@umary.edu") Or txtPassword.Text.Trim = txtRetypePassword.Text.Trim Then
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmdEmail As New SqlCommand
        Dim cmdRegistration As New SqlCommand
        Dim EmailCount As Integer = 0

        Try
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=StudentGov;User ID=sa;Password=Password1"
            con.Open()

            cmdEmail = New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(UMaryEmail) As EmailCount FROM RegisteredUsers WHERE UMaryEmail='" & txtEmailAddress.Text.Trim & "'", con)
            EmailCount = cmdEmail.ExecuteScalar()

            If EmailCount = 0 Then
                ' Declare database input variables 
                Dim userId As Integer = 0
                Dim firstName As String = txtFirstName.Text
                Dim lastName As String = txtLastName.Text
                Dim hometown1 As String = txtHometown1.Text
                Dim state1 As String = txtState1.Text
                Dim zip1 As String = txtZipCode1.Text
                Dim hometown2 As String = txtHometown2.Text
                Dim state2 As String = txtState2.Text
                Dim zip2 As String = txtZipCode2.Text
                Dim phoneNum As String = txtPhoneNumber.Text
                Dim emailAddress As String = txtEmailAddress.Text
                Dim password As String = txtPassword.Text
                Dim boolCar As Boolean = False
                Dim boolUmary As Boolean = False

                If radYesNo.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                    boolCar = True
                Else
                    boolCar = False
                End If

                ' Define the command using parameterized query 
                cmdRegistration = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO RegisteredUsers(FirstName, LastName, Hometown1, State1, ZIP1, Hometown2, State2, ZIP2, PhoneNum, UMaryEmail, Password, Car) VALUES (@txtFirstName, @txtLastName, @txtHometown1, @txtState1, @txtZipCode1, @txtHometown2, @txtState2, @txtZipCode2, @txtPhoneNumber, @txtEmailAddress, @txtPassword, @RadYesNo)", con)

                ' Define the SQL parameter '
                cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtFirstName", txtFirstName.Text)
                cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtLastName", txtLastName.Text)
                cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtHometown1", txtHometown1.Text)
                cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtState1", txtState1.Text)
                cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtZipCode1", txtZipCode1.Text)
                cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtHometown2", txtHometown2.Text)
                cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtState2", txtState2.Text)
                cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtZipCode2", txtZipCode2.Text)
                cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtPhoneNumber", txtPhoneNumber.Text)
                cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtEmailAddress", txtEmailAddress.Text)
                cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtPassword", txtPassword.Text)
                cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RadYesNo", boolCar)

                cmdRegistration.ExecuteNonQuery()
                SendActivationEmail(userId)
                Response.Redirect("RegistrationSuccess.aspx")
            Else
                ' Duplicate Email Exist Error Message
                MsgBox("Email address already supplied.")
            End If
            ' Catch ex As Exception (Not needed)
            ' Error Executing One Of The SQL Statements 
        Finally
            con.close()
        End Try
    Else
        ' Throw Error Message 
        MsgBox("Email input error")
    End If
End Sub

   Private Sub SendActivationEmail(userId As Integer)
    Dim sqlString As String = "Server=SERVERNAME;Database=StudentGov;UId=sa;Password=Password1;"
    Dim ActivationCode As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    Dim ActivationUrl As String = Server.HtmlEncode("http://localhost:63774/ActivateAccount.aspx?userId=" & FetchUserId(txtEmailAddress.ToString) & "&txtEmailAddress=" & txtEmailAddress.ToString & "&ActivationCode=" & ActivationCode.ToString)
    Using con As New SqlConnection(sqlString)
        Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE RegisteredUsers SET UserId = '" + userId.ToString + "', ActivationCode = '" + ActivationCode.ToString + "' WHERE UMaryEmail='" + txtEmailAddress.Text + "';")
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivationCode", ActivationCode)
                sqlCmd.Connection = con
                con.Open()
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Using mm As New MailMessage("****@outlook.com", txtEmailAddress.Text)
        mm.Subject = "Account Activation"
        Dim body As String = "Hello " + txtFirstName.Text.Trim() + ","
        body += "<br /><br />Please click the following link to activate your account"
        body += "<br /><a href='" & ActivationUrl & "'>Click here to activate your account.</a>"
        body += "<br /><br />Thanks"
        mm.Body = body
        mm.IsBodyHtml = True
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
        smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com"
        smtp.EnableSsl = True
        Dim NetworkCred As New NetworkCredential("****@outlook.com", "****")
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred
        smtp.Port = 587
        Try
            smtp.Send(mm)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Email was not sent")
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function FetchUserId(emailAddress As String) As String
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=StudentGov;User ID=sa;Password=Password1")

    cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT UserId FROM RegisteredUsers WHERE UMaryEmail=@txtEmailAddress", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtEmailAddress", emailAddress)
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Open()
    End If
    Dim userId As String = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    con.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
    Return userId
End Function
End Class
```

And here is the AccountActivation page:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration


Public Class ActivateAccount
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        ActivateMyAccount()
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub ActivateMyAccount()
    Dim con As New SqlConnection()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=CISWEB\UMCISSQL2008;Initial Catalog=StudentGov;User ID=sa;Password=Password1"
        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("UserId"))) And (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("UMaryEmail"))) Then

            'approve account by setting Is_Approved to 1 i.e. True in the sql server table
            cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE RegisteredUsers SET AccountActivated=1 WHERE UserId=@UserId AND UMaryEmail=@txtEmailAddress", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Request.QueryString("UserId"))

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtEmailAddress", Request.QueryString("UMaryEmail"))
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()

            End If
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Response.Write("You account has been activated. You can <a href='SignIn.aspx'>Sign in</a> now! ")

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Message", "alert('Error occured : " & ex.Message.ToString() & "');", True)
        Return
    Finally
        con.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

As you may be able to tell already, I am flummoxed. With no error messages I'm receiving, I don't know why the SendActivationEmail function is no longer working. Someone help please! :(

Comment: Just make a diff of a backup of your working version.

Comment: Unless I'm missed it, how were you (expecting to) getting error messages (re: what is `MsgBox` in ASP.Net, and `catch` seems to be commented out)?

Comment: The catch as ex exception is commented out because it is not needed. The SQL commands that write to the database work fine. It writes correctly, the only problem is that the email does not send and the last time I tried, the activation link provided in the email does not work either, it just redirects to a blank page.

Comment: Ok, I'm once again receiving the emails but the page from the email link still displays nothing, completely blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi FlummoxedUser are you sure that have you checked your code as well ????

Take a look here :

```
 Dim ActivationUrl As String = Server.HtmlEncode("http://localhost:63774/ActivateAccount.aspx?userId=" & FetchUserId(txtEmailAddress.ToString) & "&txtEmailAddress=" & txtEmailAddress.ToString & "&ActivationCode=" & ActivationCode.ToString)
```

I think is better use httputility.urlEncode/Decode for this stuff where it use it to filter only the result of each function  or single variable.

Second one take care at your code above

this is in your page :

```
  If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("UserId"))) And (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("UMaryEmail")))
```

where have you found "UmaryEmail" key in your querystring parameters?????

Check it and you will solve your issue but check also in cmd and so on in activation page or you will make some issues :)

I hope it help you and if it solves your issue mark this as answer.

UPDATE :

```
>   Dim ActivationUrl As String = Server.HtmlEncode("http://localhost:63774/ActivateAccount.aspx?userId=" & FetchUserId(txtEmailAddress.ToString) & "&txtEmailAddress=" & txtEmailAddress.ToString & "&ActivationCode=" & ActivationCode.ToString)
```

with this task you create yout activation link which will be something like

```
http://localhost:63774/ActivateAccount.aspx?userId=1&txtEmailAddress=email@pippo&ActivationCode=123456
```

Now what's append when click on that link server handle request and create a collection data which include all the keys within your querystring

In effect you can use request.QueryString to check/retrieve values from each keys. So you can use as you did request.Querystring("keyname") to get the value for that particular parameter BUT in your case you check for a key which are not passed into the link. Pay attention that you have setup only 3 keys which are

UserID

txtEmailAddress

ActivationCode

there's no "UMaryEmail" key in request query string

Also another important stuff NEVER PASS IN QUERY STRING DATABASE FIELD :) use fantasy name or shortname which not reflect database field

example :

UserID => uid

ActivatioCode = token,acd,cd or anything you want

txtEmailAddress= email, em or any other name

Now activation page issue when you try to check your value use an if statement where check for userid key and UMaryEmail where userid could be matched coz it exist in query string but UmaryEmail is not into the request.querystring you have not provided it so if fails and nothing has been shown in page.

Here your Activation Sub revisited with some comments to better understand :

```
  Private Sub ActivateMyAccount()
    'Checking you keys in querystring

    If Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("Userid") AndAlso Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("txtEmailAddress") Then
        'here we assume that keys exist and so we can proceed with rest 
        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("UserId"))) And (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("txtEmailAddress"))) Then
            'no we can proceed to make other stuff 
            'Another stuff place you connection string within connection string section in webconfig in order to make a simple request like this one :

            'classic example for create a connection with web config file
            ' Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("yourconnectionstringname").ToString)
            Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=CISWEB\UMCISSQL2008;Initial Catalog=StudentGov;User ID=sa;Password=Password1")

                If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
                Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE RegisteredUsers SET AccountActivated=1 WHERE UserId=@UserId AND UMaryEmail=@txtEmailAddress"
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con)
                    Try
                        With cmd
                            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Request.QueryString("UserId"))
                            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtEmailAddress", Request.QueryString("txtEmailAddress"))
                            .ExecuteNonQuery()
                            Response.Write("You account has been activated. You can <a href='SignIn.aspx'>Sign in</a> now! ")
                        End With
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Message", "alert('We apologize but something is gone wrong;our techs are checking the issue.Best regards etc etc etc');", True)
                    End Try

                End Using
            End Using
        Else
            Response.Write("<h1>invalid activation links!!</h1>")
        End If
    Else
        Response.Write("<h1>invalid activation links!!</h1>")
    End If
End Sub
```

If your query is right it should work at first shot :)
Take a try and let me know and if it solve your issue please mark it as answer

**UPDATE 2:**

Your actual code is :

```
    Dim ActivationUrl As String = Server.HtmlEncode("localhost:63774/ActivateAccount.aspx?userId=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(FetchUserId(txtEmailAddress.ToString)) & "&txtEmailAddress=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtEmailAddress.ToString) & "&ActivationCode=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ActivationCode.ToString))
```

But is all wrong let me explain:

Declar your variable : `Dim ActivationUrl as string` it is ok 
Then built url so :

```
="http://localhost:63774/ActivateAccount.aspx?userId=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(FetchUserId(txtEmailAddress.text.tostring)) & "&txtEmailAddress=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtEmailAddress.text.tostring) & "&ActivationCode=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ActivationCode.ToString))
```

Where take a look to piece of code which is your : 'HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtEmailAddress.ToString)' in this manner you are passing a value system type object which is a textbox to pass textbox value you need to access to its .Text property like txtEmailAddress **.Text**

Change as per my code above and it will work (if your procedure is right)

**UPDATE CODE 3 **

Change your code with this.§be carefull don't change anything copy and paste all ActivateMyAccount Sub and delete your old one

```
Private Sub ActivateMyAccount()
    'Checking you keys in querystring

    If Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("userId") And Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("txtEmailAddress") Then
        'here we assume that keys exist and so we can proceed with rest 
        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("userId"))) And (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("txtEmailAddress"))) Then
            'no we can proceed to make other stuff 
            'Another stuff place you connection string within connection string section in webconfig in order to make a simple request like this one :

            'classic example for create a connection with web config file
            ' Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("yourconnectionstringname").ToString)
            Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=CISWEB\UMCISSQL2008;Initial Catalog=StudentGov;User ID=sa;Password=Password1")

                If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
                Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE RegisteredUsers SET AccountActivated=1 WHERE UserId=@UserId AND UMaryEmail=@txtEmailAddress"
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con)
                    Try
                        With cmd
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Request.QueryString("userId"))
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtEmailAddress", Request.QueryString("txtEmailAddress"))
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            Response.Write("You account has been activated. You can <a href='SignIn.aspx'>Sign in</a> now! ")
                        End With
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Message", "alert('We apologize but something is gone wrong;our techs are checking the issue.Best regards etc etc etc');", True)
                    End Try

                End Using
            End Using
        Else
            Response.Write("<h1>invalid activation links!! bad query string</h1>")
        End If
    Else
        Response.Write("<h1>invalid activation links!! bad not string</h1>")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to say about the "UMaryEmail" key. It is defined as one of the parameters under the signup / registry page above. In the SQL database, the email address column is named "UMaryEmail", so that's why I used that name in that if-statement query, rather than emailaddress or txtEmailAddress. Was I wrong to use that name? 

I changed the server.htmlencode to httputility.urlEncode but I'm too inexperienced to understand the difference between those two commands. Thank you for your response.

Comment: take a look in post in few minutes i will show you some example :) to help you

Comment: I have update my code with some changes to your code in order to hlp you.:)

Comment: Ok, I tried your ActivateMyAccount but for some reason I'm not receiving the email. I checked my junk email but it's nowhere to be found.

Comment: @FlummoxedUser you say : **Ok, I tried your ActivateMyAccount but for some reason I'm not receiving the email.** i make some changes in your code for activation so if your mail is not send do you have to check your code above. Debug your application to check i f an exception has been thrown

Comment: Update: I just confirmed that the emails are being sent but they aren't being received neither in the inbox nor the junk box. I'm puzzled.

Comment: I tried clicking the link created viewing from the "sent" emails and clicking the link does nothing. I tried forwarding the email to myself but there is no active link when it is forwarded. I think its a problem with the ActivateMyAccount page.

Comment: First of all remove @ from cmd.parameters.addwithvalue it is not required in vbnet, second one paste here your activation link so i can take a look

Comment: This is what the link looks like in the email when it is properly received.

Please click the following link to activate your account
 [http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a63774%2fActivateAccount.aspx%3fuserId%3d%26txtEmailAddress%3dSystem.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox%26ActivationCode%3d145ce399-f577-42d9-aeac-eca2360d0d0e]Click here to activate your account.

Comment: 1) this link is not completly right :  it should be http://localhost:63774:/ActivateAccount.aspx?userid=encodedvalie&txtEmailAddress=encodevalue etc etc 
2)txtEmailAdd‌​ress%3dSystem.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox which is equal txtEmailAdd‌​res=System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox it means that you pass ttxtEmailaddress to txtEmailAddress parameter instead of txtEmailAdd‌​ress.text which return the value of the string 
3)This link with the above 2 error never work

Comment: To make it as well httputility.UrlEncode must be placed after "=" in example http://localhost:63774/ActivateAccount.aspx?UserID= **httputility.UrlEncode(yourvalue)** &txtEmailAddress= **httputility.UrlEncode(Trim(txtEmailAddress.Text))** and so on.Place also a couple of breakpoint to see if it goe in ActivateMyAccount and then proceed to debug so you will able to understand what's happend

Comment: Removed the http:// from the beginning of the link. Now the email says:

Please click the following link to activate your account
 [localhost%3a63774%2fActivateAccount.aspx%3fuserId%3d%26txtEmailAddress%3dSystem.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox%26ActivationCode%3d6278e416-8629-4596-869c-d7a7d2f0af5f]Click here to activate your account.

Comment: but you understand if the link work or is broken @Fluxommed, check your code.:)

Comment: Changed the ActivationUrl line to:

Dim ActivationUrl As String = Server.HtmlEncode("localhost:63774/ActivateAccount.aspx?userId=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(FetchUserId(txtEmailAddress.ToString)) & "&txtEmailAddress=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtEmailAddress.ToString) & "&ActivationCode=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ActivationCode.ToString))

like that, right?

Now the email is:

Please click the following link to activate your account
 Click here to activate your account.

with no working link.

Comment: take a look in my response i will update your code there. It is all wrong :) take a look i will expalin in UPDATE2

Comment: Changed to this now:

Dim ActivationUrl As String = "http://localhost:63774/ActivateAccount.aspx?userId=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(FetchUserId(txtEmailAddress.Text.ToString)) & "&txtEmailAddress=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtEmailAddress.Text.ToString) & "&ActivationCode=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ActivationCode.ToString)

but it still isn't a URL link in the email.

Comment: @FlummoxedUser use the http it is required

Comment: yes, I did use [http://localhost:63774/ActivateAccount.aspx?userId= etc], it just does not appear in that link for some reason. The link works now but when it is clicked the page says "The page can't be displayed"

Comment: It is there, I don't know why it's not showing it - I have it like:

H T T P : / / L O C A L H O S T : 6 3 7 7 4 / A C T I V A T E A C C O U N T . A S P X ? U S E R I D =

Comment: if you had team viewer write me on skype turri.giorgio so i can check with your code we will resolve soon

Comment: Ok, other than the email being junked every time, I got the page to display now and it says "invalid activation links!!"  

-- getting close!! :)

Comment: it means that something goes wrong during validation or that not pass through the procedure to update in effect it work as well coz in 2 else block you have invalid validation link so you need to understand where is the issue.You many find me on skype with id turri.giorgio send me a message so i can help you via team viewer which is more faster and i can debug with you the issue.

Comment: Any news? have you found the issue?

Comment: Yeah, it's this line:

If Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("Userid") AndAlso Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("txtEmailAddress") Then

Comment: change Userid in userId it should be the issue.I'm not sure it match string as case sensitive.

Comment: send me your code to admin@publiadv.com.Copy and paste on a txt file
I will responde via mail in few minutes it is really strange

Comment: let me know where you send the email

Comment: email sent to admin@publiadv.com

Comment: @FlummoxedUser sorry send me activation link from your email

Comment: ok, in first if you need to change AndAlso with And my mistake and check

Comment: i cannot try the sql part i have no db for do that

Comment: ok, I changed AndAlso to And but it didn't work. I'll work on this more tomorrow.

Comment: it work perfectly at my end except the database part which i have no database to test it.Make one stuff take the code that i update now in page under "UPDATE 3 CODE" coz it work for me and should work for you too